# Unable to change profile picture while wearing hat

Tags: bug, profile-picture, winter-bash

Do I have to remove my hat before changing profile image? Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: Have you tried it? Did something not work?

Comment: Struggling to change my profile image at all actually.

Comment: Its just coming to light now because of all the hat craziness!

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now :) looks like you have to take off your hat, yes.

Comment: It's a realism feature… come on, how you gonna change your face without taking your hat off first‽

Comment: lol I like what you've done with your hat btw.

Answer (score 1):

You have to deactivate hats before changing your profile picture. Use I hate hats to make them off, then change your profile picture after that make them on again.